# Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_EMPID"). Is this CUSTOM (Warning: Classic ASP)

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I suddenly have to support a Classic ASP web app (yes, I know it's older than dirt).

I am using VS2017 to attach a debugger and debug it. When I debug the code I notice that the code appears to depend on the following variable being set

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_EMPID")
```

and I don't see where this is set anywhere. Usually, I expect server variables to be read only and provided by IIS but this looks like a custom variable and is not in this list

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

I don't have access to the web server. Is it somehow possible to configure a web site to populate this variable perhaps via an applet or some other means? If I could trace debug this code this would help me tremendously and this is one obstacle.

Comment: Looks like here's something on creating custom server variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables

Comment: Have you any idea what HTTP_EMPID is?  EMPID looks like it might stand for Employee ID.  Is your site on an internal network to which users have to log in?

Comment: It's definitely Employee ID and yes, we are on an internal network. I believe that variable is used as a sort of single-sign on to determine access. I'm just not sure how it gets populated; I don't see anywhere in the app code where it is assigned, only referenced. Hence, I thought that there was something unusual going on and suspected that Server vars may be assignable.

Comment: It's a server variable so it will be set on that server but it could well be set outside the app, probably when the user turns on his terminal and logs on to the network. In your development environment the easiest thing to do would probably be to just give it a fixed value, if you can.   If whoever wrote the thing originally had wanted to create something which was set within the app he'd probably have used a session variable or an application variable, not a server variable.

Comment: Yeah, for debugging purposes, Instead of moving the Server Variable to a local var I am moving a hard coded emp id value to the local value to simulate it. I'd like to get access to IIS see if I can spot anything unusual related to this variable but I don't have access.  Thanks

Comment: @BobTate I think you mean the `global.asa` file which allows you to set `Application` and `Session` object level variables in certain load/unload events. Has nothing to do with setting `Request.ServerVariables` as these are HTTP headers set by the IIS web server or passed in a client request.

Comment: HTTP_EMPID is probably set outside of IIS. Maybe via a Proxy? Could also be each Employee's computer / browser has a setting which sets the value.